# PHP JSON Curl issue

Tags: php, json, curl

So im trying to get a JSON return using CURL however I keep getting a NULL value.

> POST variables {mgf=userData; apiKey=123455678qwertyui}

```
<?

$data = json_encode(array(
"mgf"  => "userData",
"apiKey" => "123455678qwertyui"
)); 
$data_string = json_encode($data);
$ch = curl_init('http://www.mgf.ltd.uk/software-test/api.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$result = json_decode($result);
var_dump($result);


?>
```

Comment: Var dump the original result before decoding it as it could contain invalid characters which end up being a null after decoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here Try This

```
<?php
$data = array(
"mgf"  => "userData",
"apiKey" => "123455678qwertyui"
); 

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.mgf.ltd.uk/software-test/api.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "mgf=" . $data["mgf"] . "&apiKey=" . $data["apiKey"] );


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
var_dump($server_output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are repeating this `json_encode`

just remove one for now try like this `$data_string = $data;`

Comment: Still a NULL Value

Comment: try with complete php tag `<?php ?>`